# Reversible encryption in python

Tags: python, encryption

Short Question: Is there a proved strong reversible encryption method (in Python)?

Requirement: Do not require 3rd part of Python libraries.
Apply environment: transport data through networks.

I saw a method using `str.translate()` with a key-generated table. Here is the table generating function:

```
def get_table(key):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(key)
    s = m.digest()
    (a, b) = struct.unpack('<QQ', s)
    table = [c for c in string.maketrans('', '')]
    for i in xrange(1, 1024):
        table.sort(lambda x, y: int(a % (ord(x) + i) - a % (ord(y) + i)))
    return ''.join(table)
```

Questions about this function:

1. Is this a good/strong reversible encryption?
2. In the function 1024 is a big number, need we loop so many times to get a table that strong enough?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want strong encryption *without* a third-party library, you're out of luck--the Python Standard Library only has hash functions. If you want secure encryption you'll have to either implement something like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) yourself (this is not a good idea, as it's really easy for the inexperienced to mess up when implementing an encryption algorithm), or change your requirements and use [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/).

Answer (score 2):

An xor cipher would work nicely (if you bitwise-XOR each character of the message with its counterpart in the key, you can get back to the message again by XORing the ciphertext with the key again).

[XOR Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)

EDIT: Exactly how you acquire the key will determine the security of this cipher, but it's a fast, easily reversible cipher.

EDIT2: Specifically, see these lines from the Wiki on how you might make this a secure cipher system...

"If the key is random and is at least as long as the message, the XOR cipher is much more secure than when there is key repetition within a message.[3] When the keystream is generated by a pseudo-random number generator, the result is a stream cipher. With a key that is truly random, the result is a one-time pad, which is unbreakable even in theory."

Comment: Hi Miles, The key is a constant string (i.e. a password) using for encrypt/decrypt on both side.

Comment: @mitnk: A password..!?  No.  A password is not nearly big enough a key to provide decent encryption of anything you care about.

Comment: I saw [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) after I posting this question, and I thought this should what I want. But I will review the Cipher you provided too. Thank you.

Comment: You can generate a suitable key by seeding a pseudo-random number generator with the password. AES is more secure, however.

Answer (score 0):

you could make your own encrpytion program by using an offset factor.
ie; convert each letter into a number using ord().
add to the number using a randomly generated offset key.
convert back into letter using chr()

and to decrypt:
convert each character into a number using ord()
subtract by the offset key
convert back into letter using chr()
you know have the original message.

hope it helps you

Comment: WARNING: Do not implement your own encryption in any production system. There are way more pitfalls than you know of, and attackers are way smarter than you think.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13785414/1630446 is a good answer and you should listen to it